# iMacros Extraction - Save Current Date and Time

Tags: imacros

I have an imacros extraction script where I pull numbers from our dashboard and save it to a csv. I would like to create a new column in the csv where it logs the current date and time.

Does anyone know what I should be doing to log the current date and time?

This is my code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8031994
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=company dashboard
{{!NOW:yyyy/mm/dd_hhnn}}EXTRACT=TXT  <<--  this is the part that I need some help with 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:employeename&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:employeeposition&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=employees.CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ADD](http://wiki.imacros.net/ADD) tag to add some value to the [!EXTRACT](http://wiki.imacros.net/!EXTRACT) variable.

```
VERSION BUILD=8031994
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=company dashboard
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:employeename&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:employeeposition&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!NOW:yyyy/mm/dd_hhnn}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=employees.CSV
```

Hope it helps.